# Statistical Arbitrage, Avellaneda & Lee - Estimation of the Residual Process

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, arbitrage, statistical-finance

I am trying to calculate the trade signal outlined in Avellaneda & Lee paper "Statistical Arbitrage in the US Equities Market".

They describe their approach in appendix. Here is my attempt on simulated data:

```
# Simulate returns
window = 60
np.random.seed(42)
stock_returns = np.random.normal(0.0005, 0.01, window)
etf_returns = np.random.normal(0.0004, 0.008, window)

# Standardize
stock_returns_standardised = (stock_returns - stock_returns.mean())/stock_returns.std()
etf_returns_standardised = (etf_returns - etf_returns.mean())/etf_returns.std()

# Run regression of stock returns on ETF returns
etf_returns_with_const = sm.add_constant(etf_returns_standardised)
model = sm.OLS(stock_returns_standardised, etf_returns_with_const)
results = model.fit()

# Calculate the residuals from the regression (idiosyncratic returns)
residuals = results.resid

# Fit an AR(1) model to the residuals
ar_model = AutoReg(residuals, lags=1)
ar_results = ar_model.fit()

# Obtain the autocorrelation coefficients 'a' and 'b' from the AR(1) model
a = ar_results.params[0] 
b = ar_results.params[1] 


# Calculate the signal
s_score = -a * np.sqrt(1 - b**2) / ((1 - b) * np.sqrt(np.var(residuals)))
```

There is some issue with this calculation as visually the signals time series does not make sense to me when I apply the logic to my actual data.

As many of the concepts here are new to me, I would appreciate any help with correcting my approach.

Comment: Please provide a DOI link to the paper

Comment: What programming language is that?

Answer (score 1):

From memory they assume that the sum of residuals is a mean reverting process, whereas your code assumes a random walk in the residuals + no correlation between the stock and ETF return process. I would suggest attempting this using actual trading data from Yahoo or other free resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What changes do I need to make to model is as a mean-reverting process? I have some actual data in place but trying to work out the correct calculation here

Comment: @arkon Look at the CIR process. Any type of process that has a random walk + mean reversion component will be type of mean reverting process. All you need basically is $dx_t = \alpha (\mu - x_t) d_t + \beta dW_t$. The $ \alpha (\mu - x_t) d_t $ component makes the process revert to $\mu$ at the rate of $\alpha$.